# Nested Loop Time Complexity for( i = n; i > 0; i /= 2) VS for( i = n; i > 0; i/=2) for( j = 0; j < i; j++)

Tags: java, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

I'm not able to find out Algo A and Algo B's time complexity, Please help me Guys !!!

Algo A :

```
for(int i=n; i>=1; i/=2)
    some statement
```

If I'm not wrong,

```
i = n;
i = n / 2 to the power of 1;
i = n / 2 to the power of 2;
i = n / 2 to the power of 3;
i = n / 2 to the power of 4;
.................
.................
i = n / 2 to the power k;

Algo A terminate when,

n / 2 to the power of k < 1
Therefore k = log n, Algo A take logn time;
```

Algo B :

```
for(i=n; i>=1; i/=2)
   for(j=0; j<i; j++)
      some statement
```

Guys I'm not able to find out Algo B's time complexity so how to calculate this and correct me if I'm wrong with Algo A

Comment: If "some statement" runs in constant time, the algorithm A indeed runs in *O(log n)*. What trouble do you encounter to calculate the time complexity of algorithm *B*?

Comment: The same logic your already used with `some statement` being a simple loop (complexity of which I hope you know).

Comment: If same logic applies with Algo B "some statement " execute n + n/2 + n /4..........n / 2 to the power of k , So complexity will be O(logn) or O(N) ?

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: if "*some statement*" runs in constant time, then *algorithm B* runs in *O(n)*.

Let us first analyze the inner loop:

```
for(j=0; j<i; j++)
    some statement
```

Since `j` iterates from `0` (inclusive) to `i` (exclusive), it thus means it will thus perform `i` operations.

Now we can analyze the outer part:

```
for(i=n; i>=1; i/=2)
    // i operations
```

Here `i` thus starts with `n`, is each time divided by `2`, and each iteration, we perform `i` tasks.

This thus means that the total number of tasks is:

```
 n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ... + 1
```

The above is a known sequence:

```
 m
---
\          -k           -m
/     n * 2     = (2 - 2  ) n
---
k=0
```

Here `k` thus ranges from *0* to *log<sub>2</sub>n*, and thus the total number of instructions is *(2-2<sup>log<sub>2</sub>n</sup>)× n* or *(2 - 1/n)× n* and thus *2× n - 1*. We can simplify that to *O(n)*.